# OpenCL: Parallel execution of kernels from different programs

Tags: opencl

I have two OpenCL applications that I want to execute in parallel on a GPU.  Suppose the name of the first application is A1.c and its kernel is named as a1.cl. The kernel a1.cl requires 600 CUDA cores for execution. Suppose the second application is A2.c and its kernel is named as a2.cl. I want to execute kernel a2.cl of the program A2.c on the remaining 400 CUDA cores of the GPU. The purpose is to reduce the execution time of two concurrently executing programs in comparison to when both programs are executed one by one through increasing device utilization of the GPU. However, when I launch both A1.c and A2.c simultaneously, their respective kernels a1.cl and a2.cl are not executing in parallel. 
My question is how can I execute kernels of two different programs, in parallel, on the GPU. 
Note: I am using Nvidia GTX 760 GPU.

Comment: This is driver-specific behaviour, nothing you can control from OpenCL perspective at least without fundamentally changing both applications.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to modify the programs, you can use sub-devices. This allows you to split a single OpenCL device into multiple with non-intersecting compute units, theoretically allowing truly parallel execution of two or more kernels. However, I believe this would require running both kernels from within the same host program, which may not be feasible for you.

The exact way you partition the device depends on your needs, so I would recommend [reading through the reference manual](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/) about device partitioning. There may be other bottlenecks preventing parallel execution depending on how your system is configured and how the programs use OpenCL.

Comment: But the problem is that clCreateSubDevices is not supported on either AMD or NVIDIA GPUs.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's anything that you can do, unless there's some driver-specific feature.